# onActivityResult() "accidental override" error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, camera, android-camera-intent

So i'm making this app, that captures an image, and that image is used further to extract text from it. I found this code, to access the camera and capture image (in a fragment):

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private val CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1888
    var button: Button? = null
    var imageView: ImageView? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        button!!.setOnClickListener {
            fun onClick(view: View?) {
                val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                startActivityForResult(
                    intent,
                    CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE
                )
            }
        }
        return root
    }
    fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                val bmp = data.extras!!["data"] as Bitmap?
                val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
                bmp!!.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream)
                val byteArray: ByteArray = stream.toByteArray()

                // convert byte array to Bitmap
                val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
                    byteArray, 0,
                    byteArray.size
                )
                imageView!!.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

But there is an "accidental override" error with onActivityResult() method, and i don't know how to fix that: [image: error message]

I've tried adding this to MainActivity class, hoping for the best:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

But it doesn't seem to help. I am a total beginner, but i've got to make this app real quick, so will be grateful for any advice or explanation.

upd: I've also tried adding keyword override, but i get error "onActivityResult() overrides nothing"

Comment: You're missing the `override` keyword for `onActivityResult` in your Fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition of `OnActivityResult()` isn't correct. It needs to have the same signature as the method you are trying to override. You need this:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?)
```

You need the question mark on the last parameter type `Intent?` because the value of this parameter may be `null`. This will match the signature of the method from `Fragment` that you are trying to override.

Answer (score 1):

you must override `onActivityResult` function like `onCreateView` or `onDestroyView`. So just add override keyword to left of `fun onActivityResult()`

Comment: I've tried, but i get error saying it overrides nothing

Comment: did you tried make Intent as nullable. 
Wrong: ```override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent)``` 
Correct: ```override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?)```